# AngularJS: 'Unknown provider' error for $sce in version 1.2.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.3 which is supposed to enable the SCE service by default. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=SaveApp&p1=Error: [$injector:unpr]   
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24sce 
at Error (native)
```

This is my code:

```
var AwesomeApp = angular.module('AwesomeApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router'], function($httpProvider, $dialogProvider) {
```

And a little further down:

```
AwesomeApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$compileProvider', '$sce', function($routeProvider, $compileProvider, $sce) {

$routeProvider.
    when('/', {templateUrl: $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl(chrome.extension.getURL('app.html')),   controller: 'searchResultsController'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

Any ideas why there's an **Unknown Provider** error?

Answer (score 5):

#### `$sce` is a service (not a provider)

You cannot inject services into config blocks only providers.

#### What you can do is to inject `$sceDelegateProvider` and create a whitelist:

```
.config(function($sceDelegateProvider){

  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self','http://*.url.com/**']);

})
```

#### from [$sceDelegateProvider docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24sceDelegateProvider#methods_resourceUrlBlacklist):

> The $sceDelegateProvider provider allows developers to configure the $sceDelegate service. This allows one to get/set the whitelists and blacklists used to ensure that the URLs used for sourcing Angular templates are safe.